# Remap CTRL+SHIFT+C to CTRL+C in Yakuake

Tags: unity, gnome, 20.04, shortcut-keys, kde

I run Ubuntu Unity 20.04.

I have installed `yakuake` as my favorite dropdown terminal. While `gnome-terminal` has let me set my copy/paste shortcuts to `CTRL+C/CTRL+V`, `yakuake` offers no such customization in its keyboard shortcuts.

However, if you click inside Yakuake, you get a menu that lists `copy` and `paste` as options. If you right-click those, you get a "Configure Shortcut..." option. Then you can change the shortcut. However, that persists only for that one Yakuake session, as [another used found out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/532478/how-do-i-change-paste-shortcut-for-yakuake).

I downloaded the Yakuake source and searched for "Configure Shortcut..." so that I could figure out how to manually configure the shortcut and make it persist. However, I unfortunately didn't find anything relevant.

How can I permanently change this setting? Surely there's a configuration file *somewhere* that I can edit?

Comment: To be clear, if you [set the keyboard shortcuts to the combination you desire](https://bit.ly/3ok6o4m), they are not persistent ? or only the ones for copy/paste ?

Comment: @RobertRiedl that menu does not allow you to set copy-paste shortcuts. The only way to re-set the combination for copy/paste is by right-clicking inside the yakuake terminal, and then right clicking once more on the "copy" or "paste" menu options.

Comment: Right, I've been using yakuake for a long time but recently switched over to guake (which is literally the same) - you might try it since the option for copy/paste is actually in the keyboard shortcuts and it _is persistent_ in guake.

Comment: any luck with either guake or manually building yakuake ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks related to https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=412496, with the fix available since [v20.07.08](https://invent.kde.org/utilities/yakuake/-/commits/v20.07.80). Since [the Ubuntu 20.04 package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/yakuake) is on `v19.12.3` it won't have the fix.

> Make it possible to configure the konsolepart shortcuts
>
> This patch allows the user to configure the by konsolepart provided actions. For example it wasn't possible to configure the copy/paste shortcuts. Also many the "X is an ambiguous shortcut" can now be fixed and remapped if the user so desires.

To try that fix you can follow the [instructions to build from source](https://invent.kde.org/utilities/yakuake#basic-build-and-installation-instructions):

```sh
git clone https://invent.kde.org/utilities/yakuake.git
git checkout v20.07.80
cd yakuake
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../
make
sudo make install
```